# Present string different in View than what it's set in ViewModel

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I'm working on a project on Windows Phone 8 w/ SQLite, and I've been working with dates and times, and recently I've had to start using some aggregate functions to select some data, but these can only be implemented if the datetime strings are formatted in a certain way ([SQLite DateTime](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)) so I've had to change the formatting of these values so I get the results I expect from the aggregate queries.

My problem is that these formats aren't really the most appealing when presenting the data to the user. For example, before using aggregate functions, I was displaying a duration as "23h 32m 21s" (h'h 'm'm 's's') or a date as Tuesday 31 March 2015 (dddd dd MMMM yyyy) but I had to change these to the formats SQLite uses to perform aggregate queries, so they now read 00:00:00 for duration and 2015-03-31 for dates, etc.

Is there any way where you can change the format when presenting the data to the user regardless of how it's formatted and inserted into the database in the ViewModel/C#? I've tried using a StringFormatConverter and setting the parameter to my preferred format, but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel can have a property with a getter that formats and presents the value:

```
public string FormattedDate
{
    get { return Date.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy"); }
}
```

Alternatively, your View may perform the formatting itself. e.g. With WPF:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}}" />
```

Comment: WinRT doesn't allow the use of StringFormat to my knowledge, that's why I tried the converter. I don't think I can do it the getter way you mentioned because it would interfere with the way I'm inserting into the database, unless you mean making a completely separate getter or something?

Comment: In my example, `Date` is the `DateTime` property containing the actual value as obtained from the database, while `FormattedDate` is a separate `String` property that simply returns that value as a string formatted for display. You can then bind directly to the formatted string property instead of the original date. So long as your intent is only to *display* the value rather than *modify* it (since you're binding to a `String` rather than a `DateTime`), this does the trick nicely.

Comment: Also, you could post your StringFormatConverter code and maybe get an answer as to why it's not working.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying with the FormattedDate route. So, for example, I have a simple string that gets the date when a person presses a button. I had to change the format to "yyyy-MM-dd" so that I could use some aggregate functions on that date (selecting data based on month);

    SleepDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

The above "SleepDate" is bound to a textblock.

Comment: That format isn't the nicest to look at when the data is presented to the user, so if I wanted to change the format to "dddd dd MMMM yyyy" without affecting what I'm doing with the database, queries, etc. I'd just do the following;

    public string SleepDateFormatter
    {
        get { return DateTime.parse(SleepDate).toString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy"); }
    }

And bound "SleepDateFormatter" to the textblock instead of SleepDate?

(had to split the comment up, went over the character limit)

Comment: That might work, but it seems like it's started to become somewhat convoluted at that point. I'm not 100% certain that I get your exact scenario, but it seems like what you want to do is: 1) have a `DateTime` value that is linked with your data store by whatever means; this is the value as it is stored in your database and is kept updated along with it; 2) a separate `DateTime` value that does NOT update to reflect the database value, assigned manually when needed from the first value, and 3) any number of getter-only `string` properties which perform formatting for e.g. `TextBlock` binding.